# Ошибка при запуске: No such file or directory: ''

Tags: python, tkinter

Не появляется окно,  сразу ошибка

```
import tkinter as tk
import hashlib
def show_text():
    label_text.set('Hash, "' + f + '"')

root = tk.Tk()

road = tk.StringVar()
road1 = tk.StringVar()
entry = tk.Entry(root, width=40, textvariable=road)
entry.pack()
entry = tk.Entry(root, width=40, textvariable=road1)
entry.pack()
button = tk.Button(root, text="Click Me", command=show_text)
button.pack()
fl = open(str(road.get()))
f = hashlib.sha256(fl)
label_text = tk.StringVar()
label = tk.Label(root, textvariable=label_text)
label.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Ошибка:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Python\Test.py", line 16, in <module>
    fl = open(str(road.get()))
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: ''
```

Comment: Заголовок вопроса не соответствует содержанию.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Весь код не находящийся внутри функций или классов выше `root.mainloop()` выполняется сразу после запуска программы. Получается что вы только создаете окно, текстовое поле и сразу запрашиваете из текстового поля его содержимое. Пользователь физически не успеет ничего ввести.

Нужно перенести открытие и обработку файла в обработчик кнопки, чтобы открытие файла происходило только после нажатия на нее:

```
import tkinter as tk
import hashlib

def show_text():
    fl = open(str(road.get()))
    f = hashlib.sha256(fl)
    label_text.set('Hash, "' + f + '"')

root = tk.Tk()

road = tk.StringVar()
road1 = tk.StringVar()
entry = tk.Entry(root, width=40, textvariable=road)
entry.pack()
entry = tk.Entry(root, width=40, textvariable=road1)
entry.pack()
button = tk.Button(root, text="Click Me", command=show_text)
button.pack()

label_text = tk.StringVar()
label = tk.Label(root, textvariable=label_text)
label.pack()

root.mainloop()
```